# WorksheetFunction array size limit

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm trying to calculate the 99.5% percentile for a data set of 100000 values in an array (arr1) within VBA using the percentile function as follows:

```
Pctile = Application.WorksheetFunction.Percentile(arr1, 0.995)
Pctile = Application.WorksheetFunction.Percentile_Inc(arr1, 0.995)
```

Neither works and I keep getting a type mismatch (13).

The code runs fine if I limit the array size up to a maximum of 65536. As far as I was aware [calculation limited by available memory](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010073849.aspx#BMcalculation) since Excel 2007 [array sizes when passing to macro limited by available memory](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;177991) since Excel 2000.

I'm using Excel 2010 on a high performance server. Can anyone confirm this problem exists? Assuming so, I figure that my options are to build a vba function to calculate the percentile 'manually' or output to a worksheet, calculate it there and read it back. Are there any alternatives and what would be quickest?

Comment: I can confirm the "problem". There is an array size limit when returning an array from a UDF even in Excel 2007/2010. I also don't have any other links for you, so this is just a comment. Finally, I couldn't see in the links you posted anything that suggests the array size limit *for return values from a UDF* is limited by "available memory".

Comment: i too have the type cast error when it goes to large data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error would occur if arr1 is 1-dimensional and has greater than 65536 elements (see Charles' answer in [Array size limits passing array arguments in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237195/array-size-limits-passing-array-arguments-in-vba)). Dimension arr1 as a two-dimensional array with a single column:

```
Dim arr1(1 to 100000, 1 to 1)
```

This works in Excel 2013. Based on Charles' answer, it appears that it will work with Excel 2010.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Here is a Classic VBA example that mimics the Excel Percentile function.</strike>

[<strike>Percentile and Confidence Level (Excel-VBA)</strike>](http://www.anthony-vba.kefra.com/vba/excelvba-simulation-102.htm#Percentile_and_Confidence_Interval)

In light of Jean's exposure of the [Straight Insertion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) method being inefficient. I've edited this answer with the following:

I read that QuickSelect seems to excel with large records and is quite efficient doing so.

References:

1. [Wikipedia.org: Quick Select](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect)
2. A C# implementation can be found @ [Fast Algorithm for computing percentiles to remove outliers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3779763/892646) which should be easily converted to VB.

Comment: Watch out! It uses [straight insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort)! Straight insertion is an N² routine, and should be used only for small N e.g. N < 20, not N=100000 for which it will be quite inefficient.

Comment: Thanks JFC. I have a focus here on minimizing runtime as much as possible. Can you suggest an alternative?